# O_PATH equivalent in Linux kernel before 2.6.39?

Tags: linux, kernel, symlink, fs

In latest kernel I use the following code to operate the inode of a symlink file:

```
file = filp_open(filename, O_PATH | O_NOFOLLOW, 0);
```

If I don't add O_PATH, filp_open would fail with `-ELOOP`.

On Linux kernel 2.6.32, O_PATH is unavailable, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a direct equivalent as `O_PATH` has very specific semantics where the file itself is NOT opened. The closest thing I believe is to actually open the file in a safe way, i.e. using `O_RDONLY`. Yes, that's not quite the same thing both semantically and physically. Much more work is performed in the kernel when a file is actually opened that is not performed when `O_PATH` is used. Also, you would need read permissions on the file to open it. But otherwise, it should allow you to do what you need.